# Vim Key Mapping: How to set {rhs} to the string value returned by a function

Tags: vim

I have a file type specific mapping for executing code in the current buffer.

For .pl files:
`:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r :!echo "OUTPUT:"; perl %<cr>`

For .py files:
`:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r :!echo "OUTPUT:"; python %<cr>`

As you can see, the {rhs} differs only in the interpreter name ('perl', 'python' etc). So, I wrote a function to generate it.

```
" Creates command-string to run code in buffer.
function! GenerateCmd(prg)
    return ':!echo "OUTPUT:"; ' . a:prg . ' %<cr>'
endfunction
```

And this is where I got stuck. How do I set the {rhs} to be the string value returned by `GenerateCmd()`?

For example: `:nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r =GenerateCmd('perl')` doesn't create the same mapping as the one I hand-wrote for Perl above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the command is static (i.e. it doesn't need to be re-evaluated on every mapping invocation), you can use `:execute`, which allows to evaluate strings as Vimscript commands:

```
:execute 'nnoremap <buffer> <leader>r' GenerateCmd('perl')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for both answers!

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece of the puzzle is `:help map-expr`, where the `{rhs}` is determined by a Vimscript expression:

```
:nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <leader>r GenerateCmd('perl')
```

Note that the expression must return actual keys, so instead of `'...<cr>'` use `"...\<cr>"` inside your function; within double quotes, you can use escaped *special-key* notation (which is easier than embedding an actual `^M`).

Comment: Thank you that worked! There's a subtle difference though. Each `<leader>r` use would invoke `GenerateCmd('perl')`, whereas I intended the function to be ideally called just once, to get the _constant_ command string for a given file type. It doesn't make a performance difference here though, but I'm curious if that's possible.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure whether your command is constant, so I chose the more general solution; you're right that it doesn't matter here. See my other answer for an alternative.